# Make a file print certain lines when a specific string is typed?

Tags: string, file, python-3.x

I am trying to make a text file print out certain lines when a user types in a specific string. This is what I have:

```
userfile = open("hk.csv","rU")
userfile = userfile.readline()

id_str = input("type in the id#: ")

for n in userfile:
    if id_str in userfile.startswith(id_str):
        print(n)
```

Here is a sample text file:

```
"id#","name"
"1","ball"
"2", "tee"
"3", "cart"
"4", "club"
```

Say that the user types in `"3"` as their ID#. I would then have to return something like:

```
ID#     name 
--------------   
1       ball
2       tee
4       club
```

This gives me a TypeError; I know now that the `startswith()` method only returns a Boolean.

EDIT:

I'm going to post this answer here since the comment was too jumbled. This is the new code that I have come up with:

I had actually had changed my method and now I have come up with this:

```
userfile = open("hk.csv","rU")

id_str = input("type in the id#: ")  
#read line by line  
for i in userfile:  
newfile = i[:-1]  

#if the comparison string matches with the user input, then print out those lines. 
comparison_str = ' '  
for j in newfile:  
    if j == id_str:  
        comparison_str += j  
    print(comparison_str)

#this line is still iffy.
if comparison_str == id_str:
    print(userfile)
```

This code does not print out anything. I guess it's better than the TypeError that I got.

Answer (score 0):

`readline` returns a single line. Iterate over the file and then stop when you find the record:

```
user_id = input("type in the id#: ")

with open("hk.csv", "rU") as handle:
    for line in handle:
        if line.startswith(user_id):
            print(line)
            break
    else:
        print("No matches")
```

Or convert the entire file into a better data structure, like a dictionary.

Comment: I had actually had changed my method and now I have come up with this:

`userfile = open("hk.csv","rU")

id_str = input("type in the id#: ")  
#read line by line  
for i in userfile:  
    newfile = i[:-1]  

    comparison_str = ' '  
    for j in newfile:  
        if j == id_str:  
            comparison_str += j  
        print(comparison_str)`

Comment: I second the dictionary recommendation. You should do that.